# ALSA: Use plugin in c code while playing sound

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm playing a wav sound file with some c code such as [this](https://gist.github.com/ghedo/963382/98f730d61dad5b6fdf0c4edb7a257c5f9700d83b). It uses all the APIs:

```
snd_pcm_*
```

I would like to use the equalizer plugin:

```
libasound_module_ctl_equal.so, libasound_module_pcm_equal.so
```

found in "libasound2-plugin-equal"

How can I integrate and call an Alsa plugin from c code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simpler that I imagined:

```
snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle, "equal", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0) < 0);
```

You can pass the name of the plugin to snd_pcm_open with the right set of default file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make it part of alsa chain e.g in ~/.asoundrc add

```
pcm.plugequal {
    type equal;
    slave.pcm "plughw:0,0";
}

pcm.!default {
    type plug;   
    slave.pcm plugequal;  
}
```

Than you can use the command to play sound file

```
aplay some.wav
```

For Ctl device you can add below in ~/.asoundrc

```
ctl.!default {
    type equal;
}
```

You can just call 
alsamixer